# What is this method of finding the nth term called and who invented it?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5tBvxDM9V4, by blackpenredpen.

He demonstrates a way in order to solve recursive formulas.

I am using this method in a paper of mine and require a reference to cite in my bibliography.

Does anyone know who invented this method?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html

Comment: The method is completely standard and I really doubt that you need to cite a reference.  In any case I would not be surprised to find that there is no historical evidence as to who used the method first.  If you really feel you need a reference, cite a reputable textbook, or perhaps even the YouTube video.